# Getting an error using malloc, could be caused due previous possible mistake

Tags: c++, class, malloc

I'm trying to make custom array class.

```
template<typename T>
class Array{
public:
    Array(size_t size) : array_size(size){
        this->m_Data  = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * size);
    }
    
    void insert(size_t index, T value){
        size_t temp_size = this->array_size + 1;
        T *temp = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * temp_size );
        //memcpy(temp, this->m_Data, this->array_size );
        for(size_t l = 0; l < temp_size; l++ )
            temp[l] = this->m_Data[l];

        for(size_t i = temp_size; i >= index; i--){
            temp[i] = temp[(i-1)];
        }
        temp[index - 1] = value;
        
        free(this->m_Data);
        this->m_Data = NULL;
        this->m_Data = temp;
        this->array_size = temp_size;
        //free(temp);
        //delete(temp);
    }
    
    void append(T value){
        size_t temp_size = this->array_size + 1;
        std::cout << "temp_size: " << temp_size << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sizeof(T): " << sizeof(T) << std::endl; // returns 4
        std::cout << "temp_size * sizeof(T): " << (temp_size * sizeof(T)) << std::endl; // returns 44
        T *temp = (T*)malloc((temp_size * sizeof(T)));     // error!
    }
    
    
private:
    size_t array_size;
    T *m_Data;
};
```

If I create an array with size smaller than 10, the `malloc()` function arises an error.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Array<int> data(9); 
    data.insert(1, 100);  // seams to work fine
    data.append(100000);
}
```

If I use `free(temp)` in the `insert()` function, some values in the array are junk, but it seams logic to use: the error in the `append()` function might be related to this. Otherwise, the `insert()` function works fine.

`T *temp = (T*)malloc((temp_size * sizeof(T)))` in the `append()` function is basically the same as in the `insert()` function.

How come?

Comment: 1) Why are you using `malloc` and `free` in a C++ program?  2) I can easily break your code by declaring a `Array<std::string> data(9)`, all due to `malloc` and `free` usage, regardless even if you got this code to work for `int`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not  pro coder, just using using what i know and also be compatible with C. i haven't tried with other data types yet.

Comment: C++ and C are two different languages.  Regardless of how much `C` you know, C++ is not the same, and trying to learn C++ by using C as a model is not going to end too well.  1) `malloc` does not construct objects, where objects makes up a huge part of C++.  2) Your `Array` class lacks a copy constructor, and assignment operator, and a destructor.  If you take a look at the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and go to the **Managing resources** section.  You see the flawed code there looks close to your code.

Comment: Aside from other issues, you may wish for your array to grow by more than one element on each insert or append, and only grow when necessary. Doing so minimizes the number of allocations and copies.

Comment: @Chris I was looking at the GNU header of Vector, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/libstdc++/api/a01641_source.html, but it quickly leads to ‘sub stuff‘ found in other headers where again ‘sub‘ elements from other headers are used.

Comment: Off by one error.   In the first loop of `insert()`,  `this->m_data` initially has `this->array_size` elements, but `this-array_size + 1` elements are copied from it to `temp`.   That is accessing non-existent elements, and causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Arthur O'Dwyer explains everything you need to know—and supplies source code—for a "roll-your-own" vector class, in this excellent talk from CppCon 2019: [Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ). Here is the [cheat sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ&t=40m58s) with all the source code. Highly recommended for anyone making their first foray into dynamically allocated data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is that this results in a buffer overwrite, since `temp_size` is the number of items you allocated, thus `temp[temp_size]` is not valid:

```
T *temp = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * temp_size );
//...
for(size_t i = temp_size; i >= index; i--)
{
    temp[i] = temp[(i-1)]; // <-- Overwrite on first iteration
```

This probably should be:

```
for(size_t i = temp_size - 1; i >= index; i--)
{
    temp[i] = temp[(i-1)];
```

But there are other errors that can be easily triggered by using your code.

For example, `Array<std::string>` or simply `Array<any_non_trivial_object>` will cause an issue due to the usage of `malloc` and `free` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: Darn, that was it, now it works, lousy overlookable error! Thnx. the ‘destructor‘ was planned for later, but i dind't think of copy constructor or assignment, is it to copy array? ... and how should i look at assignment operator, any examples that fits my code? ‘new‘ was further down in the code, but got stuck on this error.

Comment: See [the rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: In reality my code contains many debug lines, but that one slipped, but thnx for the advice, the code does have overloaded operator.